# Trying testing API in postman

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to check an api in postman, check the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkt32.png)

This is my code

```
     login: (req, res) => {
        const body = req.body;
        const otp_value = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
        body.otp = otp_value

        getUsersByMobile_service(body.mobile_number, (err, mobile_results) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            if(!mobile_results){
                create(body,(err, results) => {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            message: "Database Connection Error"
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            setOtpToUser_service(body, (err, results) => {
                if(err){
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        message: "Database Connection Error"
                    });
                }
                if(!results){
                    return res.status(422).json({
                        message: "Invalid Mobile Number"
                    });
                }else{
                    sendOtp.send(body.mobile_number, "COCOAL", otp_value, (error, data) => {
                        // console.log(data)
                    });

                    return res.status(200).json({
                        message: "OTP sent successfully"
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    },
    verify: (req, res) => {
        const body = req.body
        getOtpFromMobile_service(body.mobile_number, (err, get_otp_results) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            if(!get_otp_results){
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: "Invalid OTP"
                })
            }else{
                if(get_otp_results){
                    let jstoken = ""
                    if(body.otp == get_otp_results.otp){
                        get_otp_results.otp = ""
                        jstoken = sign({
                            result: get_otp_results
                        }, process.env.KEY_FOR_JSTOKEN,{
                            expiresIn: "10h"
                        });

                        return res.status(200).json({
                            message: "Login Successful",
                            token: jstoken
                        });
                    }else{
                        return res.status(401).json({
                            message: "Invalid OTP"
                        });   
                    }
                }else{
                    return res.status(422).json({
                        message: "Invalid Mobile Number"
                    });
                }
            }
```

It is inserting all the null fields into the table

```
mysql> select * from user;
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name | mobile_number | authtoken |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
|    NULL | NULL      |          NULL | NULL      |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And at the same time it is sending the otp as well.

```
Documents/Projects/something/something$ [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
s live at :  3000
969169
```

Comment: Kindly tell me what is the problem. I would be grateful if anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

change the type of request in postman to `json` like the following photo

[image]